# How much spot checking do I need?

Tags: statistics

I'm working on software in which Component X is used 130 times. X is going to be replaced with a new and improved version, Component Y.

We need to regression test every instance where X is replaced with Y, which is going to take a lot of effort. If we get through the first 50 tests and there are no failures, intuitively, we're not going to expect any of the other 80 to fail. The risk may be small enough that it's not worth continuing.

Is there a way to quantify this risk? If we start with assumption that there's a 10% chance that at least of the regression tests will fail, **how many successful tests do we need to reduce that risk to 1%?**

To put it another way:

1. A bag contains 130 balls that are either red or black.
2. There is a 10% chance that the bag contains at least one red ball.
3. How many black balls must be drawn to reduce that chance to 1%?

I've gotten as far as relating the problem to this familiar thought experiment, but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that probability of not drawing a red ball given there are any is $p$, and we draw total of $n$ balls.

Total probability of not drawing a red ball is thus $0.1 \cdot p + 0.9$, and probability of having a red ball given we didn' draw one is $\frac{0.1 \cdot p}{0.1 \cdot p + 0.9} = \frac{p}{p + 9}$.

Now we need $\frac{p}{p + 9} \leqslant 0.01$ or $p < \frac{1}{11}$.

Given that $p \leqslant \frac{130 - n}{130}$ (probability of not drawing any red ball if there is only one), $n = 119$ will be sufficient (and $n = 118$ will not, as if there is just one red ball, we will have probability of $\frac{12}{130} > \frac{1}{11}$ of not discovering it).

Comment: Thanks. I’m more concerned with the average case than the worst case, but this is the start that I needed. (Don’t worry, I’m not building a self-driving car! :))